# Increasing Java heapsize in R has no effect

Tags: java, macos, r, rjava

on Linux and Windows I call

```
options( java.parameters="-Xmx512m" )
```

before loading any R libraries which rely on `rJava`. Especially when reading and writing large Excel files using `XLConnect` (which uses Apache POI) this becomes necessary. However, on my Mac (OSX 10.8) this seams to have no effect:

```
options( java.parameters="-Xmx512M" )
library("XLConnect")
> Loading required packages: XLConnectJars
> Loading required packages: rJava
> XLConnect 0.2-1 by Mirai Solutions GmbH
> http://www.mirai-solutions.com ,
> http://miraisolutions.wordpress.com
xlcMemoryReport()
> Amount of free memory in the Java Virtual Machine (JVM):  60.72328 MB
```

My Java version is:

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Any hints what I could have missed?

Comment: Do you actually get OutOfMemory errors? The heap may not grow to its max size until it needs to (and free memory reflects that).

Comment: @Thilo so many thanks! I had another problem with the heap size this morning and indeed OutOfMemories. Than I fixed this problem but didn't run the memory demanding tasks but just checked `xlcMemoryReport. If you post your comment as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you actually get OutOfMemory errors?

The heap may not grow to its max size until it needs to, so the "free memory" reported will just be the memory available within the current allocation (which may be allowed to be extended if necessary until that maximum is finally reached).

Comment: see my comment on my question :-)

Comment: I get out of memory errors, though regardless of my max heap size.  I think this question should be revisited.